# Nested try catch when copying a file

Tags: powershell, try-catch, copy-item

I'm copying files from a file location in a .csv, which doesn't contain the extension of the file. I attempted to hard code '.tif' which worked, but there are other file types which are being missed. I attempted to use the below, but it throws an error, stating that the path is showing as C:\users...

```
    if (-not (Test-Path -Path $path -PathType Container)) {
        New-Item -Path $path -ItemType Directory >$null
    }
    #Perform Copy
    echo "Copying document and Prepending Document Date"

    try {
        $copy = [IO.FileInfo]$_.'Document File Path'+'.tif'
        $copy | Copy-Item -Destination "$path\$($_.'Document Date')_$($copy.Name)"
    } catch {
        try {
              $copy = [IO.FileInfo]$_.'Document File Path'+'.pdf'
              $copy | Copy-Item -Destination "$path\$($_.'Document Date')_$($copy.Name)"
        } catch {
            $copy = [IO.FileInfo]$_.'Document File Path'+'.jpg'
            $copy | Copy-Item -Destination "$path\$($_.'Document Date')_$($copy.Name)"
        } finally {
            $copy = [IO.FileInfo]$_.'Document File Path'+'.doc'
            $copy | Copy-Item -Destination "$path\$($_.'Document Date')_$($copy.Name)"
        }
    } finally {
        $copy = [IO.FileInfo]$_.'Document File Path'+'.docx'
        $copy | Copy-Item -Destination "$path\$($_.'Document Date')_$($copy.Name)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use the `*` wildcard for file extension?

Comment: Do you have a reason for checking for the specific file extension?

Comment: @vonPryz I tried that, but it doesn't copy the file. Here is what I used:

$copy = [IO.FileInfo]$_.'Document File Path'+'.*'
 $copy | Copy-Item -Destination "$path\$($_.'Document Date')_$($copy.Name)"

Comment: @I.TDelinquent When I ignore the file extension, I get an error what the file path did not exist.

Comment: @LFuller I believe that's because of how you are building the `$copy` variable.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do, let me know if this is correct: Check a directory from the CSV exists, if it does, fine. If not then create it. Check for a file under the directory and attempt to move it

Comment: @I.TDelinquent Yes, that's right! For reference, If I produce the csv with an extension hard coded, then the above code in my comment works fine (minus the +'.*')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work if you have only one matching file at a time:

```
$name = Split-Path -Leaf $_.'Document File Path'
$src  = $_.'Document File Path'
$dst  = Join-Path $path ('{0}_{1}' -f $_.'Document Date', $name)
Get-ChildItem "${src}.*" | Copy-Item -Destination { $dst + $_.Extension }
```

If that would incidentally match other files that you don't want to copy (e.g. `$name` is "foo" and you want to copy "foo.tif" but not "foo.bar.txt") you could filter by basename before copying:

```
Get-ChildItem "${src}.*" | Where-Object {
    $_.BaseName -eq $name
} | Copy-Item -Destination { $dst + $_.Extension }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Any harm in using the second option for an exact match either way? Any difference in performance?

Comment: Well, you have an additional step there, so there will be *some* performance impact, but I'd expect it to be negligible.

Comment: Appreciate it, thank you. If I wanted to ignore files with a particular extension, such as '.pdf', how would I go about this?

Comment: Add a condition `-and $_.Extension -ne '.pdf'` to the `Where-Object` filter.